# Recursive function not returning correct array

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I'm using to build an array-based grid for a game. It takes in a "blank" 8x8 array as follows:

```
const initialBoardState = [
    [['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x']],
    [['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x']],
    [['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x']],
    [['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x']],
    [['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x']],
    [['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x']],
    [['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x']],
    [['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x'],['x']]
]
```

I've written a function `generateBoard` to assign `['O']` at two random coordinates on the array.

Simply put, the function adds a single `['O']`, then calls itself again with the intention of adding a second `['O']`.

There is a `count` variable that counts how many times the function is executed. Because I only want two `['O']`, the function terminates when `count>1`

However, the function is returning a grid with only one `['O']`. Thoughts as to what I've done wrong?

Function:

```
let xRandomValue;
let yRandomValue;
let coordinates = [];

const generateBoard = (board) => {
  let count = 0
   xRandomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
   yRandomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);

  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    if (i === yRandomValue) {
      for (let j = 0; j < board[yRandomValue].length; j++) {
        if (j === xRandomValue) {
          board[yRandomValue][xRandomValue] = ["O"];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  coordinates.push(xRandomValue)
  coordinates.push(yRandomValue)
  count++
  if(count>1){
    generateBoard(board)
  }
  return board;
};


console.log(generateBoard(initialBoardState))
```

Comment: WHY do you need to loop over everything to set random vaues?unsure how your code ever calls generateBoard() since count would be 1.

Comment: And why do you need recursion here? Just use a loop to generate `n` random `x` and `y` values (while keeping track of already used values) and then use `board[y][x] = ["0"]` to set the values.

Comment: `const generateBoard = (board) => {
  for (var i=0; i<2;i++) {
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    board[y][x] = '0';
  }
  return board;
}`

Comment: _“There is a `count` variable that counts how many times the function is executed.”_ — Not if you set it to 0 every time you call it.